# Why does my Jet Reports NL Lookup not refresh?

Tags: excel

We have a Jet Report reading a Dynamics NAV 2013R2 Sales Invoice Line table. We have created it on our system with Start Date and End Date options with a Lookup, =NL("Lookup","Sales Invoice Line","Posting Date"). This works as expected and displays the appropriate list of dates from our test server. Test Server data is a couple years old and the last date is in year 2018.

When we upload the Jet Report to the client and run it, the lookup dates are not refreshed, it displays the same list of dates as our test server (e.g. the last date displayed is in year 2018). How can we force the Lookup to refresh on the client side so it displays the full list of dates?

I have tried uploading the report in design mode and also in report mode. Neither results in the correct list of Dates being displayed.

Comment: Is there a limit somewhere that limits the number of rows returned by the NL Lookup function?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there is a limit to the number of rows displayed. I added a filter to the Lookup to sort by Date descending and the latest dates showed up as expected.